# Mongodb Write Performance goes down when Wired Tiger cache utilization goes above 80% of total cache size

Tags: mongodb, performance, load-testing, mongo-java-driver

I am running load test on Mongodb using java driver at client side.

Cluster Setup includes: 3 Mongos, 3 Config Servers, 3 shards each having 3 members( Primary, Secondary and a Arbiter node).Everything is running on separate machine.

Config servers and shard nodes are configured with 4 GB wiredTiger cache size.

At client side, I am inserting same document every time. Here _id is auto generated. Size of the document is fixed and is 900 bytes only.

While running a load of 40k transaction per second from single client using insertOne operation, I am getting close to 40k transaction per second. But this TPS drops significantly and gradually becomes **zero** after complete RAM utilization both(WT cache and file system(Linux) cache). i.e, I am not able to insert any more document into DB.

However I tried to insert documents using second client to check if it is client side issue. But it also failed to insert.

IOStats of the server having primary node:
[image: IOStats of the server having Primary Node]

MongoStats at primary node:
[image: MongoStats at primary node]

MongoTop at primary node:
[image: MongoTop at primary node]

Comment: Please don't use Indian measurements like crore. That's just going to confuse people.

Comment: One shall look at several aspects of any write heavy system.

1) ( virtual ) server io capacty
2) disk type, slower disk, slower write performance
3) number of index being updated per document/record write call
more index updates, slower writes
4) in case of mongodb , write acknowledgement also plays part.

Comment: Also refer this that asks bout monotonically increasing shard key and shaded system not being utilized fully

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/83160